# How can I make a running total that keeps its value outside of the switch case?

Tags: c#, random

I am writing a polyhedral die rolling program. The user can input the type of dice to be rolled and the number of dice. It is working well except that I'm not sure how to add up the total and then print it out.
It is successfully printing each individual roll, though, so I know it is working as far as generating the random numbers in the proper range determined by the user. I wanted to print the total at the end of the program, but it is not working.
Does the value of the variable disappear after the program leaves the switch case?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int typeOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int numberOfDice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    // Assigns random generator parameters to user's choice of dice type
    switch (typeOfDice)
    {

        case 4:
            for(int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
            {
                int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                int total = currentRoll + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(currentRoll + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
             }
             break;
            //....
       case 100:
            for (int count = 0; count < numberOfDice; count++)
            {
                int currentRoll = rnd.Next(typeOfDice);
                int total = currentRoll + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(currentRoll + 1);
            }
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You are defining the variable total inside the for loop. If you want it to be accessible after the switch, define it before the switch.
2. If total is the sum of all dice rolls, you should be incrementing it with each dice roll, not setting it. i.e 
   `total += currentRoll + 1` instead of   `total = currentRoll + 1`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can evaluate whether the user enters a value other than 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20 or 100? I was thinking maybe the or operator ||, but can I use that to evaluate multiple values? I know it can be used for 2, as in if (numberOfDice != 4 || numberOfDice != 6), but I'm not sure how to do it with more than 2 values. Or do I have to use a several separate if statements? Is there a better way? Arrays, perhaps? I've never messed with arrays yet.

Comment: It looks like you are handling each type of dice separately in the switch, so you can add a default case (with default:) and handle invalid dice types there. You could also look into HashSet and membership testing. For future reference, a followup question like this should be in a new question instead of a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable total before the switch statement and it will work.  Because you're declaring it inside the for loop, it goes out of scope once the for loop is finished.